# can't set model attribute in a controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a simple model named "test" that looks like this:

```
export default DS.Model.extend ({
  name: DS.attr('string')
  })
```

My model hook in the "test" route is defined as follows:

```
 export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model() {
     return this.store.createRecord('test');
     }
 });
```

I tried to assign an initial value to model.name in the "test" controller, but I can't get the 'set' to work.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  init: function() {
    let mod = this.get('model');
    this.set (mod.name, "dummyName");
    }
})
```

Ember inspector says mod=null.  What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**
I tried the 4 syntax changes as recommended in the comments below.  None seem to work.  I get the following error messages for each:

None of the 4 suggested syntaxes seem to work.
I get the following error messages for each:

1. Assertion Failed: Path 'model.name' must be global if no obj is given.  Error: Assertion Failed: Path 'model.name' must be global if no obj is given.
2. You need to provide an object and key to `set`. Error: Assertion Failed: You need to provide an object and key to `set`.
3. Cannot read property 'set' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of null
4. object in path "model" could not be found or was destroyed. Error: Property set failed: object in path "model" could not be found or was destroyed.

Seems to be telling me that 'model' is null for some reason.

**Update:**My controller actually looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  init: function() {
    this.set ('model.name', 'dummyName');
  },
  actions: {
    save() {
      this.get('model').save();
      this.transitionToRoute('scenarios');
      return false;
    },
    cancel(){
      this.transitionToRoute('scenarios');
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

With this controller, I get this error:

Property set failed: object in path "model" could not be found or was destroyed. Error: Property set failed: object in path "model" could not be found or was destroyed.

If I took out the 'init' hook, the 'save' & 'cancel' actions works fine.  Naming seems to be ok; I used ember-cli pods to generate the initial code

Is 'model' loaded at the time when the controller's 'init' hook is called?

Comment: Can you recreate your problem in https://ember-twiddle.com/ or put it up in a public repo?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your `route.js` file:

```
setupController(controller, model) {
  controller.set("model", model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the model is not loaded in the init hook. You could wrap your code in a run later:

```
init: function() {
  this._super();
  var _this = this;
  Ember.run.later(function() {
    _this.set('model.name', 'dummyName');
  });
},
```

Or a better way would be to set the property when creating the model:

```
return this.store.createRecord({name: 'test'});
```

as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Adding 'run later' still didn't fix the problem.  I get this error message:

      "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined."

I'll try initializing in createRecord, which should work fine.  I'm still curious as to why the 'set' didn't work in the 'init' hook though.

Comment: did you include the _this? The error your experiencing there is because the scope isn't the same inside the run later

Comment: Have also edited to include this._super(); which you must always call if you overwrite the init method on anything.